# How many threads to launch in OpenMP?

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

I am new to OpenMP Programming and I have executed several open-mp sample programs on GCC . I wanted to know how will I decide on how many threads to launch (i.e how to decide the parameter of omp_set_num_threads() function) to get the better performance on dual core intel processor .

****This is my sample program****

```
#include<math.h>

#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#define CHUNKSIZE 10
#define N 100000
#define num_t 10

void main ()  
{
    int runTime;
    int i, chunk;
    int a[N], b[N], c[N],threads[num_t];
    int thread_one=0,thread_two=0;
    clock_t start,end;
    omp_set_num_threads(num_t); 
    /* Some initializations */
    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = b[i] = i + 2.0;
    chunk = CHUNKSIZE;
        #pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,chunk,threads) private(i)
    {

            #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,chunk)
            for (i=0; i < N; i++)
            {
                c[i] = pow((a[i] * b[i]),10);
                threads[omp_get_thread_num()]++;

            }
    }  /* end of parallel section */
    for(i=-1;i<num_t;i++)
    printf("Thread no %d : %d\n",i,threads[i]);
}
```

Comment: You test several values, and pick the one that gives best "performance" on the machine you're running on.

Comment: Is that the only solution? If i launch only 2 threads doesnt it gives better performance since it is a dual core machine ? I am really new so need to know how does this work .

Comment: Yes, that's the only way to find out the optimal for a given program on a given machine. Number of cores/threads is a good setting to start with, but test with more and less. Memory and memory bandwidth are also important for some problems, so the CPU count isn't the only thing that matters.

Comment: Does that depend on number of iteration or the chunck size i give .

Comment: If you don't have any special knowledge, then let the implementation decide.

Comment: Thank you mat and david . Those answers were really helpful .

Comment: Hint: change `dynamic` scheduling to `static` to get some performance boost.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, set for a first try your threads number to the number of cores of your machine. Then try to  decrease this number to see if any improvement occurs.

By the way, rather than using `omp_set_num_threads`, setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable is way more convenient to do such tests

Answer (score 3):

My advice: **don't bother**. If it's a computationally intensive app (which openmp is mainly used for and what you have here) then the library itself will do a good job of managing everything.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal number of threads depends on many parameters and it is hard to devise a general rule of a thumb.

For compute intensive tasks with low fetch/compute ratio, it would be best to set the number of threads to be equal to the number of CPU cores.

For heavy memory-bound tasks increasing the number of threads might saturate the memory bandwidth way before the number of threads becomes equal to the number of cores. Loop vectorisation can affect the memory bandwidth for a single thread significantly. In some cases threads share lots of data in the CPU cache, but in some - they don't and increasing their number decreases the available cache space. Also NUMA systems usually provide better bandwidth than SMP ones.

In some cases best performance could be achieved with more threads than cores - true when lots of blocking waiting is observed within each task. Sometimes SMT or HyperThreading can hide memory latency, sometimes it can't, depending on the kind of memory access being performed.

Unless you can model your code performance and make an educated guess on the best number of threads to run with, just experiment with several values.